# I'm getting an error "BAD REQUEST" while establishing an connection between Airflow and Snowflake

Tags: airflow, snowflake-connector

I'm New to Airflow while connecting to Snowflake From Airflow I'm getting an error like "BAD REQUEST" I have installed all required dependencies according to the constraints file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.3/constraints-3.8.txt so anyone please help me to find the exact issue.
the error of the picture [bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxYgq.png)

Comment: where you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

until yesterday I was facing the same issue with establishing the connection with Snowflake from airflow. I might have found a bug with airflow. The workaround for now you can try is:

Delete the existing connection and create a new connection with your details.

```
Connection id:
Connection Type: Snowflake
Host:12345.eu-west-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com
schema: public
login:
password:

extra: {
    "extra__snowflake__account": "12345", 
    "extra__snowflake__database": "Sampledb", 
    "extra__snowflake__insecure_mode": false, 
    "extra__snowflake__region": "eu-west-1.aws", 
    "extra__snowflake__role": "accountadmin", 
    "extra__snowflake__warehouse": "compute_wh"}
```

Leave rest of it blank.

Once you fill the details, test the connection before you save it. You would not face a BAD REQUEST issue. Unfortunately, if you open the connection again and test, the connection will always return BAD REQUEST.

Don't worry about it as the connection would work. Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

The connection testing functionality in the UI currently doesn't support using the custom form fields (like Database, Warehouse, Role, etc. for the Snowflake connection). This should be fixed [with this PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/21330) in Airflow 2.3.

For Snowflake specifically, you can add those custom fields in Extra as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a connection to Snowflake using CLI:

```
$ airflow connections add --conn-type Snowflake \
    --conn-description 'Connection to Snowflake for bla-bla-bla' \
    --conn-uri 'snowflake://<user>:<password>@<host>/<schema>?role=<role>&account=<account>&database=<database>&region=<region>&warehouse=<warehouse>' \
    foo_snowflake
```

You also can use Airflow UI to add a Snowflake connection. In this case following options should be specified in the "Extra field":

```
{"role": <role>, "account": <account>, "database": <database>, "region": <region>, "warehouse": <warehouse>}
```

Corresponding fields in the form e.g. "Role", "Account", "Database", "Region" etc. should be empty.
This approach I used in Airflow version 2.2.2.